# UIButton name not changing the first time it is selected from UITablView index cell name

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

```
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.strSlctdCntry);
btnSlctCurrency.titleLabel.text = [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@",appDelegate.strSlctdCntry];
btnSlctCurrency.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

The above code is `NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.strSlctdCntry);` index name get from `UITablView` is OK but button name is not changing the first time. It is only changing the second time.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try using `setTitle` method for your button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :
For setting the button title :

```
[btnSlctCurrency setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",appDelegate.strSlctdCntry] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For Alignment

```
[btnSlctCurrency setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
```

Comment: it is working fine but Alignment is not working ..

Comment: @areddy Use : [btnSlctCurrency setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];